# foreach() executing same line again and again

Tags: php

I have a sql field wehre values are like

1,2,3,4,5,6

if fetch those values and explode them below

```
$amenities = 1,2,3,4,5,6
$amenities_check = explode( "," , $amenities );
```

Then I run a foreach loop

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($amenities_check as $amenities_conf)
{
    if( $amenities_conf != "" && $amenities_conf == 6)
    {
    ?>
        <li class="available_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <li class="not_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
    <?php
    }
    if ($i++ == 1) break;
}
?>
```

Now the problem is that this loop is display the same line 6 times and display the correct class of li when it meets the 6 digit in the data if i apply $i++ it only check the first data in the dataset.

Any help that foreach look for the desired values like 1 2 3 and do the function according to it ..

Thanks

Comment: The line `if ($i++ == 1) break;` runs every time around the loop; it will be true immediately, and so will exit the loop after showing one `li`. I'm not quite clear what you were trying to do with it, though, so can't offer corrected code.

Comment: As a separate point, the `$amenities_conf != ""` is redundant, since `$amenities_conf` couldn't equal both the empty string (`""`) and `6` at the same time, so just testing `$amenities_conf == 6` is enough.

Comment: I have 1 - 21 in my sql field every number claims separate title...
like if 1 = smooking, 2 = pets and so on...
so for each will look for the 1 if 1 is in the sql database then li with active class else li with not active class this is what i want

Comment: So you only want to show the smoking status once, based on whether `6` appears *somewhere* in the list? If so, you don't want a `foreach` loop at all, just [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array), or perhaps to re-arrange your data as a hash of booleans (`array(1=>true, 2=>false)` and so on).

Comment: Yes this is what i want can you please write a sample code please

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
foreach($amenities_check as $amenities_conf) {
  if ($amenities_conf == 6) {
    ?>
    <li class="available_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
    <?php
  }
  else {
    ?>
    <li class="not_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
foreach($amenities_check as $amenities_conf) {
  if ($amenities_conf == 6) {
    ?>
    <li class="available_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
    <li class="not_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
```

or like the guys above said, use in_array().

```
<?php
if (in_array("6", $amenities_check)) {
  ?>
  <li class="available_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
  <?php
}
?>
<li class="not_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
```

Comment: but as to reach 6 foreach will run 6 times and display the else condition 5 times and display if condition 1 time  i want to solve this that extra 5 lines of data

Comment: Yes this will display the "not_amen class" 5 times and the "available_amen class" 1 time. I'm not sure what you actually want then?

Comment: i dont want to display the not_amen class 5 times if 6 is present display available_amen if 6 is not there display not_amen only 1 time

Comment: I edited my code. I put it outside of the foreach so it will only display once, easy :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, what you actually want to know is if there is a 6 anywhere in the array, so you don't want to be outputting anything at all in the loop. The simplest approach is to use the fairly self-explanatory [`in_array` function](http://php.net/in_array); as simple as this:

```
if( in_array('6', $amenities_conf) )
{
?>
    <li class="available_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <li class="not_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
<?php
}
```

Alternatively, break apart your logic from your display by looping through the database result once and preparing structured data based on it. The below is probably over-kill for this example, but shows a general approach:

```
// While retrieving data from the DB
$amenity_names = array(
     1 => 'pets',
     // ...
     6 => 'smoking'
);
$included_amenities = array();
$amenities_check = explode( "," , $amenities );
foreach ( $amenities_check as $amenity )
{
     $name = $amenity_names[$amenity];
     $included_amenities[$name] = true;
}

// In the View / template code
if( $included_amenities[['smoking'] )
{
?>
    <li class="available_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <li class="not_amen">Smoking Allowed</li>
<?php
}
```